# Javascript replace string and get string replaced

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I am getting a sometimes random string that will always contain [] with special string inside of it. I would like to use the text inside each bracket and use it in a function to replace the text inside each bracket. Here is an example:
So far I have

```
let string = 'test [a] test2 [b]'
let test = string.replace(/\[(.+?)\]/g, ""+getValue(text inside bracket replaced here)+"")

function getValue(text) {
    //this function will return a value based on the certain text it receives
}
console.log(test)

'test [replaced text based on a value] test2 [replaced text based on b value]'
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument of `.replace` can be a replacer function, so you can put `getValue` there. The capture group will be in the second argument, so you'll have to alter `getValue`'s parameter list:

```
let string = 'test [a] test2 [b]'
let test = string.replace(/\[(.+?)\]/g, getValue);

function getValue(wholeMatch, textInsideBrackets) {
    //this function will return a value based on the certain text it receives
}
```

Comment: Excellent, clear example - nice one.